# How to display number of rows in a Google worksheet in the Chrome Tab icon (email notification style)

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, notifications, counter, worksheet

I'm a novice so please explain it like I'm 5.

I would like to know when a new entry is made into a shared google worksheet.

I have the worksheet pinned in my Chrome session and thought the best way might be a count in the tab icon showing the row count - if this Changes I have a new entry.

The Worksheet has multiple tabs but I am only concerned with one of them, and entries will be made one line at a time.

Open to any other solutions that would alert myself and my team to new entries in the sheet.

Hope this is clear.

Thanks,
Ken.

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to programming, creating an extension that tracks a Google sheet might be too advanced because of the OAuth2 API and other Google Data APIs that would be needed.

If you just want a notification, you can [use this method](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/91588?hl=en) for setting up email notifications from the sheet itself. I would then set up a filter in your email client to grab those notification emails and put them in a folder so you can see the count.

If you're okay with using third-party services, If This Then That ([ifttt.com](http://www.ifttt.com)) is a great way to set up triggers for many different services, including Google Docs.